# How to populate Isolated Storage for Windows Phone application

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there a recommended way to initialize the data in Isolated Storage for Windows Phone 7 application before it is run for the first time? Right now the best solution I can think of is putting a flag in IsolatedStorageSettings and checking for its presence on in the application Launching event. If the flag is not present I initialize several objects in code and save them to Isolated Storage and set the flag so they are not set the next time the application is run. Is there a better way to do this? Should I add the objects in serialized state as some kind of resource or it is acceptable to initialize them in code? I expect that they would require like a thousand lines of code.

Comment: Hi there, i recommend to look here http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage--intro-to-isolated-storage -All about wp7 Isolated Storage

Comment: Is there anything related to initializing on first run in this articles? The best practices section does not have anything related to this.

Comment: They show there how to check if file/folder exits so you always check if the file/folder exists before you create a new one. is that what you mean?

Comment: Well I was wondering if there is some way to declare that you want some data in IsolatedStorage when the application is installed. I know the APIs to work with IsolatedStorage but I was wondering if there is a way that is more... lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you can create your files and add them to the project. And if you are sure that you will not be editing your files than just keep them like that. The files will go into your installation folder.
Or if you think that you are going to edit them and want to keep the changes saved, than copy them from the installation folder to the application storage folder. 
Here is a link in which a database which was added as a reference to the project is copied from installation folder to storage folder of the app.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286411(v=vs.92).aspx

Do the same for your files and everything will be fine.

The second part of your question. Well after this just check for one file/folder in the app storage folder and if it says yes it is there than do not copy your files from installation folder to application storage folder.

And if you are trying to make the files when the application launches than just add a check before the creation code is run. Where you will search for a file/folder existence. And if it exists do not run the file creation code.